# Find the smallest element greater than data, or the successor (Binary Search Tree)

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have a BST class and BSTNode class, both which extend comparable.I need to find the smallest element greater than data, or the successor,
from the binary search tree. I know I have two cases

1: The right sub-tree is non-empty, then successor is the leftmost node
the right sub-tree

2: The right sub-tree is empty, then successor is the lowest ancestor of
the node containing data, whose left child is also an ancestor of given
data. Example:

```
               73
               /  \
             34   90
            /  \
            32  40
```

If we need to find the nextLargest of 40, you would return 73.

```
public T nextLargest(T data) {
      return helperNL(data, root);
}
    private T helperNL(T data, BSTNode<T> root) {  
        if (data == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You can't look for null data");
        }
        if (root == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (root.getRight() != null) {
                BSTNode<T> dummyNode = root.getRight();
                //getting the leftmost node
                while (dummyNode.getLeft() != null) {
                    dummyNode = dummyNode.getLeft();
                }
                return dummyNode.getData();
       }
        return null;
    }
```

This is the code I have so far. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You don't have a binary search tree. It's just a random tree. I suggest that the type be `T extends Comparable<T>` and store lower values in the left branch

Comment: Actually, I do. I have a class BST<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements BSTInterface<T>. Also, a BSTNode class: public class BSTNode<T extends Comparable<? super T>>. This is just a small part of a larger code.

Comment: Note that finding the successor is simply [in-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order) and is different to finding the upper bound for a query (if that is what's meant by *smallest element greater than data*).

Comment: Well, I have a List<T> inorder() that returns a list. I don't think that they are the same. Considering I have two separate methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just go for basic inorder traversal. Take any static variable to store the data of the node just traversed. If it is equal to the data (of which you have to find the successor), print the current node.